# Execute Unidata Process from the shell command lines?

Tags: unidata

Is it possible to execute the Unidata process from the Unix Command line??

If it's possible, can anyone please let me know how to??

I just want to add some Unidata Processes into the shell script and run it from the Unix

Cron job.

[Unidata Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBgvm.png)

[Unix Command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbmnI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  There are several approaches, depending on how your application is setup.

1. Just pipe the input to the udt process and let 'er rip

> ```
> $cd /path/to/account
> $echo "COUNT VOC" | udt
> ```

This will run synchronously, and you may have to also respond to any prompts your application puts up, unless it is checking to see if the session is connected to a tty.  Check the LOGIN paragraph in VOC to see what runs at startup.

2. Same, but run async as a phantom

> ```
> $cd /path/to/account
> $udt PHANTOM COUNT VOC
> ```

This will return immediately, the commands will run in the background. Have to check the COMO/*PH* file for the output from the command. It's common for applications to skip or have a cut down startup process when run as a phantom (check for @USERTYPE)

3. If none of the above work because of the way your application is written, use something like expect to force the issue.

> ```
> spawn udt
> expect "ogin:"
> send "rubbleb\r"
> etc.
> ```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect for more info on expect